# applying conditional on data in pandas dataframe and ignore headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have data in this format in CSV file. I want to have a excel file where all the values greater than 0 replaced with 1. Now I have tried this code but problem is either I loose the header (years eg 1960/1961) or I get error when I ignore them.

[image: Current data]

Here is my code trail.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("first.csv")
data1 = data.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')

data1 = (data1>0).astype(int)
data2 = data1.combine_first(data)
print(data2)
```

I want the output to be like

[image: Required Format]

Here is the URL to csv file, you can download to run the given code.
https://gofile.io/?c=eWd049

Comment: Your csv file contain `,` character in the beginning which is causing Ms Excel to fail loading it for me..

Comment: try any online csv viewer then e.g google sheets

Answer (score 0):

numpy has a .ceil method that round up and .floor to round down.
`numpy.ceil()
numpy.floor()`

so it should be something like (once you change year/year as column title):

```
import numpy as np
for column in data.columns:
    data[column]=data[column].apply(lambda x: np.ceil(x) if x<1 else np.floor(x))
```

for column title issues: specify the dtype and check the separator.